# FDRE with RST tied to 0 to synthesize a value at reset at 1: hardware value not correct, why?

Tags: fpga, synthesis

Here is the code of a developer (let's ignore the name of the signals):

```vhdl
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    buff_eop    <=  1;
  end else if (tx_usr_axis_tvalid & tx_usr_axis_tlast & tx_usr_axis_tready) begin
    buff_eop    <=  1;
  end else if (tx_usr_axis_tvalid & tx_usr_axis_tready) begin
    buff_eop    <=  0;
  end
end
```

Synthesis result:

[image: fdresynthesis]

Truth table of the LUT:

[image]

- I'm unable to explain the developer why the code doesn't produce the correct behavior in hardware (but does it in simulation)

#### UUG974:

[image: FDRE]

Using a proper "else" doesn't solve anything:

```vhdl
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    buff_eop    <=  1;
  end else begin
    if (tx_usr_axis_tvalid & tx_usr_axis_tlast & tx_usr_axis_tready) begin
      buff_eop    <=  1;
    end else if (tx_usr_axis_tvalid & tx_usr_axis_tready) begin
      buff_eop    <=  0;
    end
  end
end
```

#### Assumptions

- The FDRE's reset value is 0, the compiler tries to synthesis that using LUT and a feedback.

  - Conclusion: Any registers have to be reset to 0 and nothing else, this should be a developer rule.
- The only explanation I can have is looking at the logic table, it stays forever in the `Q=D` state that might be undefined (or 0 here) forever.

  - even though the reset signal (that isn't the FDRE's reset) is high, something prevent the FDRE to become high for whatever reason. Looking at the LUT's truth table, the output should be 1 when **I4** (our `rst` signal) is high.
- It works in simulation.

#### Test from nanofarad's comment:

```vhdl
module top(
    input logic clk,
    input logic rst,
    input logic tx_usr_axis_tvalid,
    input logic tx_usr_axis_tlast,
    input logic tx_usr_axis_tready
);

(*mark_debug="true"*)logic buff_eop;

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    buff_eop    <=  1;
  end else if (tx_usr_axis_tvalid & tx_usr_axis_tlast & tx_usr_axis_tready) begin
    buff_eop    <=  1;
  end else if (tx_usr_axis_tvalid & tx_usr_axis_tready) begin
    buff_eop    <=  0;
  end
end

endmodule
```

[image: buff_eop as markdebug]

[image: truth table]

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating this. My attempt to synthesize this code, with all signals directly broken out to IOBs, gives me a single FDSE ("D Flip-Flop with Clock Enable and Synchronous Set") that gets cleared to 0 by `tvalid  && tready` and set to 1 (with higher priority) by `rst || (tvalid && tlast && tready)`. I'm using Vivado 2019.1 targeting an xc7a12.

Comment: (to add to above, the synthesized schematic I get is https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzkYt.png)

Comment: Interesting! I'm using Vivado 2020.1. I find the same result as you if I isolate and export the signals as ports. Nevertheless by keeping `buff_eop` as internal with `mark_debug="true"`, I get the FDRE with the LUT feedback. I edited my question with the result.

Comment: Can you post the truth table for the LUT5 that you get in your latest screenshot? It seems topologically correct (i.e. it can create any of the needed transitions including the no-transition state given how it's wired), but the truth table is needed to know for sure. With your code I replicate the output you have exactly, and the truth table makes the post-synthesis behavior as expected.

Comment: I added the truth table... I simulated and I know it works logically. Nevertheless, not in hardware... I'll need to investigate more with an ILA.

Comment: The only way buff_eop becomes 0 is `tvalid&tready`. And it might never become 1 if there is no clock while `rst=1`. (`rst` is the pll's locked signal inverted, the clock is running at least few cycles before it's locked). Very strange...

Comment: What do you mean "work" in simulation? Did it "work" in all 3 levels of simulation? Behavioural, Post-synthesis, Post-route?

Comment: Behavioral and post-synthesis(netlist), nevertheless it's complicated because external resets such as PERST# and GTY's common have a role here...

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. What is the expected and actual output and which signal.

Comment: Same as @MituRaj, what is the actual problem here?

Comment: Reg: _Any registers have to be reset to 0 and nothing else, this should be a developer rule_: No. It is never the case. "developer" (Read "designer") decides the reset value.

Comment: The register should be high after the reset. It isn't in the actual hardware.

Comment: Rakend: If you knew how many times a designer has to change its decisions based on the tool he uses...SV/verilog or tool's features not or badly supported and so on. Best practices are here to avoid wasting time. I tend to use the natural value/behavior.

Comment: That's weird. How did u confirm buffeop is low always even after reset and how did u do reset in the hardware.

Comment: I think despite, mark debug attribute, your internal signal got optimized, so it's showing as 0. Take it outside as a port and connect an LED to confirm. Tool won't ever override the reset values specified by the user in RTL.

Comment: The reset was released much before the clock starts, therefore the register never goes to the reset value. (MMCM locks faster than GTY's common) Wrong reset for the clock. What I need to investigate is why it works on a different project using the same clock/reset topology. Anyway, thank you all!